# Urban Airship Implementation on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, urbanairship.com

I am trying to add libUAirship-1.4.0.a by going to Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries and locating the library on disk, after doing so i am still getting an error saying use of undeclared identifier: UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey, UAirship, UAPush.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Create Airship options dictionary and add the required UIApplication launchOptions
    NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

    // Call takeOff (which creates the UAirship singleton), passing in the launch options so the
    // library can properly record when the app is launched from a push notification. This call is
    // required.
    //
    // Populate AirshipConfig.plist with your app's info from https://go.urbanairship.com
    [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

    // Set the icon badge to zero on startup (optional)
    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];

    // Register for remote notfications with the UA Library. This call is required.
    [[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    // Handle any incoming incoming push notifications.
    // This will invoke `handleBackgroundNotification` on your UAPushNotificationDelegate.
    [[UAPush shared] handleNotification:[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
                       applicationState:application.applicationState];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have posted the solution on <a href="https://github.com/AlexyIbrahim/UrbanAirshipNotification">github</a>, soon I'll be posting a project as well

Answer (score 2):

You need to #import the header file associated with the library in order for the symbols to be available. For this library I believe you want to add the following to the top of your source file:

```
#import "UAirship.h"
#import "UAPush.h"
```

Comment: i did that already but still getting an error on the import saying "UAirship.h" file not found

Comment: Then you haven't added the directory containing the header files to the header search path of your target.

Comment: i did add ../Airship (recursive), i actually did follow all the steps on urban airship website but didn't work, if you have a working copy of the application i'll be very thankful if you can send it to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, UA's documentation sux.

Comment: This worked for me, but just to note that even though XCode was unable to autocomplete either of these they still import fine (so long as you followed the step in the official docs to add the Airship directory to the header search path).

Comment: I made the mistake of adding /Airship/** to "Library Search Paths" instead of "Header Search Paths". Solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many different variations of how to set the **Header Search Paths**.
For me, this worked. Airship folder is in same level as the project.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Airship
```