# Undeclare identifier

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

I am trying to add libUAirship-1.4.0.a by going to Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries and locating the library on disk, after doing so i am still getting an error saying use of undeclared identifier: UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey, UAirship, UAPush.

```
@implementation SampleAppDelegate
//@synthesize UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey;

-(void)dealloc 
{
    self.controller = nil;
    self.window = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{           
    CustomPushHandler *customHandler = [[CustomPushHandler alloc] init];
    [UAPush shared].delegate = customHandler;

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [_window addSubview:_controller.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [self.window setRootViewController:_controller];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Display a UIAlertView warning developers that push notifications do not work in the simulator
    // You should remove this in your app.
    [self failIfSimulator];

    // This prevents the UA Library from registering with UIApplication by default. This will allow
    // you to prompt your users at a later time. This gives your app the opportunity to explain the
    // benefits of push or allows users to turn it on explicitly in a settings screen.
    //
    // If you just want everyone to immediately be prompted for push, you can
    // leave this line out.
    [UAPush setDefaultPushEnabledValue:NO];

    //Create Airship options dictionary and add the required UIApplication launchOptions
    NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:[UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey]];

    //[takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

    // Set log level for debugging config loading (optional)
    // It will be set to the value in the loaded config upon takeOff
    [UAirship setLogLevel:UALogLevelTrace];

    // Populate AirshipConfig.plist with your app's info from https://go.urbanairship.com
    // or set runtime properties here.
    UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];

    // You can then programatically override the plist values:
    // config.developmentAppKey = @"YourKey";
    // etc.

    // Call takeOff (which creates the UAirship singleton)
    [UAirship takeOff:config];

    // Print out the application configuration for debugging (optional)
    UA_LDEBUG(@"Config:\n%@", [config description]);

    // Set the icon badge to zero on startup (optional)
    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];

    // Set the notification types required for the app (optional). With the default value of push set to no,
    // UAPush will record the desired remote notification types, but not register for
    // push notifications as mentioned above. When push is enabled at a later time, the registration
    // will occur normally. This value defaults to badge, alert and sound, so it's only necessary to
    // set it if you want to add or remove types.
    [UAPush shared].notificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert);

    // Register for remote notfications with the UA Library. With the default value of push set to no,
    // UAPush will record the desired remote notifcation types, but not register for
    // push notfications as mentioned above. When push is enabled at a later time, the registration
    // will occur normally. This call is required.
    [[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                                 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                                 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];


    // Handle any incoming incoming push notifications.
    // This will invoke `handleBackgroundNotification` on your UAPushNotificationDelegate.
    [[UAPush shared] handleNotification:[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
                                applicationState:application.applicationState];


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: did you copy past this question from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131933/urban-airship-implementation-on-ios

Comment: @meda The text of the question is identical but the code is quite different.

Comment: @user2767343 Did you add the proper `#import` statements to this .m file?